# React Native Square In-app payment, something went wrong, code:unexpected

Tags: javascript, react-native, payment, sandbox, square

I'm currently adding the Square In-App payment SDK(version 1.3.1) to the React Native app. Running it on iPhone 8 iOS:13.3

I basically copied the code from Square's doc, here is the code:

```
async componentDidMount(){
    this._loadCreditCardInfo()

    await SQIPCore.setSquareApplicationId('MY_SANDBOX_APP_ID')
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        await SQIPCardEntry.setIOSCardEntryTheme({
          saveButtonFont: {
            size: 25,
          },
          saveButtonTitle: 'Add  ',
          keyboardAppearance: 'Light',
          saveButtonTextColor: {
            r: 255,
            g: 0,
            b: 125,
            a: 0.5,
          },
        });
      }
}

onCardEntryComplete() {
    // Update UI to notify user that the payment flow is completed
  }

  async onCardNonceRequestSuccess(cardDetails) {
    try {

      console.log(cardDetails);
      await SQIPCardEntry.completeCardEntry(
        this.onCardEntryComplete(),
      );
    } catch (ex) {
      // payment failed to complete due to error
      // notify card entry to show processing error
      await SQIPCardEntry.showCardNonceProcessingError(ex.message);
    }
  }

  onCardEntryCancel() {
    // Handle the cancel callback
  }
  async onStartCardEntry() {
    const cardEntryConfig = {
      collectPostalCode: true,
    };
    await SQIPCardEntry.startCardEntryFlow(
      cardEntryConfig,
      this.onCardNonceRequestSuccess,
      this.onCardEntryCancel,
    );
  }
```

This is what I got [image: something went wrong. please contact the developer of this application and provide them with this error code unexpected]

I'm pretty sure my card info is correct!

Comment: Hi, are you testing in sandbox? If so, please be sure to use a sandbox test card: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/testing/test-values#test-values. There's a known issue with "unexpected" error when using a real CC instead of sandbox CC.

Comment: @sjosey Hi, thank you for your comment, but after entering one of the test card (4111111111111111), it takes forever to load. Do you have any idea?